Traefik with Redis for distributed locking
I'm using Traefik to proxy requests to our backend mainframe so that requests within a session are processed one at a time (since our mainframe is non-transactional). I'm trying to integrate redis with Traefik to provide a distributed lock mechanism with a custom plugin using Go. A very cutdown version of my traefik plugin is this.
import (
    github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis
)

type Config struct {
    Headers map[string]string `json:"headers,omitempty"`
}

func CreateConfig() *Config {
    return &Config{
        Headers: make(map[string]string),
    }
}

type MyApiProxy struct {
    next     http.Handler
    headers  map[string]string
    name     string
    template *template.Template
}

func New(ctx context.Context, next http.Handler, config *Config, name string) (http.Handler, error) {
    conn, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
}

func (a *MyApiProxy) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
}

and my go.mod has this
module github.com/mycompany/my-api-proxy-plugin
go 1.23.2
require github.com/gomodule/redigo v1.9.2

The problem is the call to redis.Dial which then calls the redis client library code in conn.go which has this line of code
do.dialContext = do.dialer.DialContext

which uses the Go dial.go library. Problem is the method signatures are different between Go:
func (d *Dialer) DialContext(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (Conn, error) 

and the Redigo library
func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)

so it fails with a mismatch of func signature.
Has anyone else had success with integrating Redis with Traefik. I also used the redis-go library but the traefik interpreter didn't like that it used the Go unsafe.go library.
